# Auto filling formula VBA

Tags: vba, excel

Looking for some help with a VBA function

I have data on two sheets I need to perform an index match on.

The data size will vary every time the compare is run.

I have coded the VBA to call the data and populate both sheets but running the comparison is causing a problem.

I have created the below function, its running without error but not populating the formula in cell starting J2 to end of the J range.

```
Sub FormulaFill()

Dim strFormulas(1 To 1) As Variant

With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Export Worksheet")
    strFormulas(1) = "=INDEX('sheet1'!E:E,MATCH('Export Worksheet'!A2,'sheet1'!A:A,0))"

    .Range("J:J").FillDown
End With

End Sub
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

W

Image after updated code applied

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were writing the formula to an array variable, not a cell, then you tried to fill the entire column by using `J:J`. This means it was trying to fill the entire column with the contents of cell `J1`, the top cell, not `J2`.

Here is the code with corrections.

```
Sub FormulaFill()

    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Export Worksheet")
        .Cells(2, 10).Formula = "=INDEX('sheet1'!E:E,MATCH('Export Worksheet'!A2,'sheet1'!A:A,0))"
        .Range(.Cells(2, 10), .Cells(.Cells(.Rows.Count, 9).End(xlUp).Row, 10)).FillDown
    End With

End Sub
```

The `.Cells(.Rows.Count, 9).End(XlUp).Row` determines the last filled row of column 9 (I) and the code uses that number in the range to use for the autofill of column 10 (J)

Comment: Thank you very much for the response, I updated the code.

It is now populating the formula to column J, however its populating the formula to the end of the entire workbook and not the end of the data on the sheet.

I gave included an image above

Comment: As your original code seemed to to do that, I assumed that was the desired behaviour. I've updated the code to stop at the last filled row based on column 9(I).

Answer (score 0):

It's because you're not filling the cell with the formula.

```
Sub FormulaFill()

Dim strFormulas(1 To 1) As Variant

With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Export Worksheet")

strFormulas(1) = "=INDEX('sheet1'!E:E,MATCH('Export      Worksheet'!A2,'sheet1'!A:A,0))"
.Range("J1").Forumla = strFormulas(1) 

.Range("J:J").FillDown
End With

End Sub
```